# How do I access variables in custom elements in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a custom element on my page and need to access a variable on the app.js from the custom element. Is the only way to bind the data I need to the custom element?

```
<custom-element data.bind="data"></custom-element>
```

The reason I ask is that I am running a loop to create multiple custom-elements and don't want to bind 5 variables to each custom element like that. Just asking if there is another way?

Comment: custom elements don't have access to the outer scope. So I would say no. You could render your custom elements using <compose></compose>, which has access to the outer scope.

Comment: Bah, I didn't want to do that.  can a subscription work?  I have no clue how to do one but I saw something about it on the Aurelia site docs.\

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, but I think binding each one of the elements is right way to do it

Comment: Using the databinding system is probably the correct way to go here, but if you could create a gist with a little more detail, we might be able to provide some more focused help. You can start here: https://gist.run/?id=7e54dce4b37aba9776fd6b48289553ce&sha=d6c14e54508d0aece1b7c8e2cacd4783e927274a

Comment: All answers point to the same thing that the bind I am doing is the best way.  I will stick to it.  Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom element's template cannot access the outer scope.  This is by-design. It ensures custom elements are portable. This mirrors the way standard elements work such as `<div>`, `<a>`, etc.  You can use those elements anywhere.  The only way to pass them data is via their attributes.

If you want to tightly couple your custom element to the outer view model, you could do something like this:

```html
<custom-element app.bind="$this"></custom-element>
```

*but this is not recommended*

Comment: Jeremy, you forgot to add "but this is not recommended."